# Calculate only parts that are not #NA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let`s say we have a sheet like that is:

[image]

As you can see there are several `NA` values in this formula.

The formula in my results column is like that:

`=A2 *B2 + C2*D2`

How to calculate this formula correctly, with the NA values, so that they get ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel does not handle error values in calculations very well.

One approach might be to check each value for an error before using it

E.g. in E2 use

=IFERROR(A2,0) *IFERROR(B2,0) + IFERROR(C2,0)*IFERROR(D2,0)

Copy to E4

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer! Is there an automatic function, which can apply `IFERROR()` on each of this cases? My problem is that my formula is extremely long...

Comment: Since anything times 0 is 0, and multiplication takes precedence over addition, this can be shortened to:  `=IFERROR(A2*B2,0) + IFERROR(C2*D2,0)`

Answer (score 1):

The same principle as @teylyn but avoids changing your existing formulae in ColumnE, so without lengthening these. Take advantage of the fact that each element of the extremely long formulae is a product and either replace the `#N/A` with `0`, or since presumably themselves the results of formulae, wrap each of those (shorter?) formulae with their own IFERROR to return `0` where otherwise the return would be `#N/A`.